# How to make iOS text font size expand/contract with screen sizes?

Tags: ios

If a GUI designer provides an iOS design using a particular device screen size as a reference point then how can a font be made to expand or contract if the app is run on different devices?

i.e. Suppose the designed provides a single design with an iPhone 8 screen size as a reference and some text is specified to be font size 24 for example. When run on an SE that should contract to fit, when run on an 8+ it should expand to fit.
If the text is places in a label and then the constraints are set and also  autoshrink is turned on and minimum font scale is set to some value (such as 0.75) then when the app is run the font will automatically scale down when run on a small screen device such as an SE.
But a UILabel only has an autoshrink property, it doesn't have autoexpand, so how can text within a label be made to expand if necessary as well as shrinking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the font-size so big that auto-shrinking will always be invoked.

Or, set the font-size manually to a number you calculate based on dimensions.

Comment: But if a GUI designer has specified for example that the font size should be size 24 on an iPhone 8. Then if iPhone 8 is set as the base in the storyboard in order to layout the design, then how can the font size be set so big without it looking ridiculously larger than size 24 on an iPhone 8? Or if the font size is fixed at 24, then that would be too large when run on an iPhone SE and too small when run on an iPhone 8+.

Comment: If you need font-size to be set to a number very specifically, set it programmatically based on a function you write that takes into account all of the things you need it to.  There is no way to get what you want exactly with just the storyboard.

Comment: It doesn't need to be exactly specific, but anyway wouldn't hardcoding a font size have to be done for each device and therefore not be scaleable to future as-yet unreleased devices?  This seems like a such a fundamentally remarkably omission from iOS/Storyboards I must be missing something? How can there be no ready made way to make UILables' *and* their text content auto expand/shrink depending on the device size. Surely with iOS at 11 there must be something by now? It seems utterly utterly ridiculously ludicrous that there isn't. Am I therefore missing something?

Comment: It is not very usual to set the font size based on device size -- I can't think of an app that does that (maybe games, but they don't use UILabel usually). A very common thing is to use Dynamic type and let the user set it: https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/visual-design/typography/ -- generally, designers should be using these size guidelines and not specifying point sizes for any device

Answer (score 0):

If you set the constraints correctly, and set the font to auto shrink, with a minimum font size, the label *will* resize so that it’s not ridiculously large on smaller screens.If you need a specific size for a particular phone you can then also programmatically specify a font size for that phone, and it Should still be ok if Apple bring out different sized screens.